# Finding length of function using improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, arc-length

So I want to find the length of the function $y = a - 2\sqrt{ax} + x$ in the interval $(0, a)$, assuming $a > 0$.

I found the derivative: $ y' = 1 - \frac {\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x}} $

Then using the formula $$l = \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2} dx$$
I get the integral:
$$l =\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}+\frac{a}{x}} dx$$

Which is improper, because at the lower bound $0$ $\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}$ and $\frac{a}{x}$ approach infinity.

$$ l = \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{2x-2\sqrt{ax}+a}*x^{-1/2} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{2x-2\sqrt{ax}+a} d2\sqrt{ax}+a$$
With substitution as suggested by the comments: $y=\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}$, $dx=-\frac{a}{y^2}dy$: (I think I made a mistake, because this one [doesn't converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bsqrt%5C%2840%292-2y%2BPower%5By%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29*Divide%5B-a%2CPower%5By%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7By%2Cinf%2C1%7D%5D))
$$l = -a*\int_{\infty}^{1}\sqrt{2-2y+y^2}*\frac{1}{y^2}dy=a*\int_{1}^{\infty}\sqrt{2-2y+y^2}*\frac{1}{y^2}dy$$

How can I solve this? And is $l = \sqrt{2}a$, because I found that as an answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763733/what-is-the-length-of-latus-rectum-of-parabola-sqrtx-sqrty-sqrta) but without integration?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: [The antiderivative is messy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%282-2*sqrt%281%2Fx%29%2B1%2Fx%29) even if you use a substitution such as $y=\sqrt{a/x}$, but the definite integral turns out nice.

Comment: Maple says $$\int_{0}^{a}\!\sqrt {2-2\,\sqrt {{\frac {a}{x}}}+{\frac {a}{x}}}
\,{\rm d}x={\frac {\sqrt {2}\ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2} \right) a}{2}}+a$$

Comment: @jjagmath I tried this: $\int(\sqrt{2x-2\sqrt{ax}+a}*x^{-1/2}dx= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int(\sqrt{2x-2\sqrt{ax}+a} d2\sqrt{ax} + a $

Comment: And by the way: that is *not* a definite integral but an improper one.

Comment: @DonAntonio oh yeah my bad, it's fixed now!

Comment: Don't post that in a comment. Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Is "the length of a function" correct terminology? I would have called this the length of the _graph_ of the function $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $t=\sqrt{\frac xa}$
\begin{align}
l =&\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}+\frac{a}{x}} \ {dx}
=2a \int_0^1 \sqrt{2t^2-2t+1}\ dt\\
=& \ a \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{2t^2-2t+1}}{t-\frac12}\ d\bigg[\left(t-\frac12\right)^2\ \bigg]\\
\overset{ibp}= &\ a+\frac a2\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{2t^2-2t+1}}\ dt 
=  a+ \frac a{\sqrt2}\sinh^{-1}(1)
\end{align}

Comment: How do you go from line 2 to 3? Don't you just multiply by $\frac{2t-1}{2t-1}$ and where does the 2 in front of the integral go? I think on the 4th line you fixed it since it's supposed to be 1/2 instead of 1 [2a(1/2+1/4...)] instead of [a(1 +1/4...)].

Comment: @Average_C_Enjoyer - u r right. just fixed it